# Probabilistic Bounds for a Strictly Positive Machine Learning Point Estimate?

Tags: machine-learning, scipy, statistics, data-science, probability

I'm trying to create some probabilistic bounds for my machine learning regression predictions. What I'm currently doing is taking the output of the regression algorithm (I'm predicting team points scored), passing it in as the mean to a normal distribution, using the team's historical standard deviation of points scored as the standard deviation for the normal distribution, and then using the CDF to get the probability of them scoring any given range of points.

The problem I'm facing is that depending on the regression prediction and the standard deviation, I could be accidentally giving 10% probability that the team will score negative points.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can take the output of a regression algorithm, use it as a parameter to a distribution (along with some sort of variance parameter), and get a probability that a team scores over N points, while keeping it to strictly positive values? AKA the probability of scoring less than 0 points should always be 0.

Everything else about my current approach works well - I'm able to combine machine learning with traditional statistics for probabilistic bounds. The problem is these negative values.

Here's a concrete example:

```
from scipy.stats import norm

#model predicts team will score 5 points
model_points_prediction = 5

#teams historical standard deviation of points scored is 3
team_points_standard_deviation = 3

#pass it parameters to normal distribution
dist = norm(model_points_prediction, team_points_standard_deviation)

#probability of scoring less than 0 points
print(dist.cdf(0))
```

And it print's out 4.7% chance of points being less than zero. What's a better solution to this that keeps it strictly positive?

Comment: How about using a probability distribution whose support is nonnegative instead of the normal distribution?

Comment: Great question, although as it's a conceptual question, it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead. Essentially you need a model which constrains possible values to be nonnegative; there are many choices. Perhaps the simplest is the truncated normal distribution (just cut off the tail and normalize the remainder to 1).